# Can I run the django and react js app on same ec2 instace and point them to a domain separately for each?

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a django app running on http://public ip of ec2:8000 on ec2 and then i have created a nginx server and its sever is like this
server
listen 80;
server_name public ip of ec2;

```
    location 
        proxy_pass http://public ip of ec2:8000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

And then i have pointed it to the a domain like server.domain.com in dns by adding a A record pointing to ec2 public ip.

Now i have also created the react js and deployed it on same ec2 and started running it using pm2 on http://public ip ec2:3000/.
Django:8000 and react js:3000 are running on different ports.

"Now how can i point it to another domain like frontend.domain.com in the dns ? As i won't have another public ip for that ec2"

- which if there i can create another nginx and point it to the  domain in dns.

I have a django app running on http://public ip of ec2:8000 on ec2 and then i have created a nginx server and its sever is like this
server
listen 80;
server_name public ip of ec2;
location
proxy_pass http://public ip of ec2:8000/

And then i have pointed it to the a domain like server.domain.com in dns by adding a A record pointing to ec2 public ip.

Now i have also created the react js and deployed it on same ec2 and started running it using pm2 on http://public ip ec2:3000/.
Django:8000 and react js:3000 are running on different ports.

"Now how can i point it to another domain like frontend.domain.com in the dns ? As i won't have another public ip for that ec2"

- which if there i can create another nginx and point it to the  domain in dns.
  Please give me a solution!

Answer (score 0):

I would not host static files in a server env if you can use sub domains. Just host the static files in an s3 bucket and point your sub domain there instead. This greatly reduces complexity since you don't have host another server and makes deployment easier too. Check this article out. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html